# ues while loop can't printf use C language

Tags: c, linux

In ubuntu,My code is:

```
 int main(){
    printf("signal test");
    while(1);
    return 0;

}
```

and it can'd display: signal test

Answer (score 1):

This is because of buffering, as no newline is printed, nothing is flushed to the output.